# Creating an attribute that can store the same value as another attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

just a quick question!

I am implementing a database using Oracle SQL Developer for school and I've come across a requirement I'm not quite sure how to implement.

Basically the database is a student management system and I'm working on the Assessment Table currently. Here is the requirement

"The Maximum_Mark attribute stores the maximum possible raw mark for the assessment(e.g., 30), while the Weight attribute stores the percentage weight of this assessment for the paper as a whole (e.g., 10%). If Maximum_Mark is not specified,then front-end applications should use Weight for both."

Does this mean that I should just set the Default Value for Maximum Mark to be whatever was entered for Weight? If so, how do I go about this? So far this is what I have but it isn't working.

```
CREATE TABLE Assessment
(
  Assessment_ID   NUMBER(10),
  ...
  ...
  Weight          NUMBER(3)
   CONSTRAINT Assessment_Weight_Null NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT Assessment_Weight_Invalid CHECK(Weight BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
  Maximum_Mark    NUMBER(3)
   DEFAULT (Weight),

   CONSTRAINT Assessment_PK PRIMARY KEY (Assessment_ID)
);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of a homework question

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a column for a default value, so `DEFAULT (Weight)` won't work.

Default values must generally be constants. You can also use Oracle functions *but they can't involve a column*, so functions like `SYSDATE`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `SYSTIMESTAMP` are allowed. You can also default to something like `TRIM('abc ')` (because it doesn't involve a column) but that doesn't help much.

That said, I don't think you need to define the default at the database level. Check the wording of the requirement (emphasis added):

> > If Maximum_Mark is not specified,then **front-end applications** should use Weight for both.

The "front-end applications" here is the key: your professor expects the substitution of `Weight` for `Maximum_Mark` to be done by the *front-end apps*, not by the database. In my opinion, you don't need to default the value at the database level.

Comment: Okay thanks, I did wonder that about the front-end applications so that makes sense!